# FME - How to convert string represenation of date to a date format that SQL Server will accept?

Tags: fme-form, translation

I have dates in the form of `07-28-2010` I am extracting from DWG filenames. I need to push these to a DateTime formatted table in non-spatial SQL Server 2008. SQL Server doesn't like them as strings coming in from the ETL apparently. How can I set the datatype in the ETL from string to datetime? Is this even what I need to do? I'm pretty sure this is my issue based on past experience with pushing dates to SQL Server and this error from FME:

```
MS SQL Server Writer: 1 attribute value(s) failed conversion, and were written as NULL values
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the FME Readers and Writers Manual:

> When writing to the database, the
>   writer expects the date attribute to
>   be in the form YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

You'll probably need to use the DateFormatter transformer to get this format.
I would:

Use a StringReplacer to replace the - with / in the date attribute
Use a DateFormatter set to %Y%m%d or %Y%m%d%H%M%S including time (be sure to get the case right)
Write it to a datetime field in the SQL Server output

Comment: Thanks Mark. I ended up using a StringSearcher and a regex to get the date out of the filename, then in a StringConcatenator I rearranged the _matched_parts to YYYYMMDD. This then inserts into the datetime SQL Server field just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Creator> TimeStamper> [^d-^b-^y] > SQLExecutor [DBMS settings] should work

http://groups.google.com/group/fmetalk/browse_thread/thread/24b057b19e55fad9/ded0a9d2baa73c81